# Mysql DISTINCT account_id and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I want to select the last (datetime) record_version ordered by datetime DESC, for every account_id

```
SELECT * 
FROM `record_versions` 
WHERE record_id='26'
GROUP BY `account_id`
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

It returns only one record for account_id, but it's not the last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a self join to get your desired result ,inner query will get maximum of your `datetime` column per `account_id` and it will join the rows from outer query with the latest `datetime` value

```
SELECT 
  r.* 
FROM
  `record_versions` r 
  JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      MAX(`datetime`) `datetime`,
      account_id 
    FROM
      record_versions 
    GROUP BY account_id) t 
    ON (
      r.account_id = t.account_id 
      AND r.datetime = t.datetime
    ) 
WHERE r.record_id = '26'
```